# Cloning SOAP UI Test Steps using Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, soapui

Recently I have started to improve my SOAP UI testing projects by using Groovy Scripts. I am just on a beginner level more often amending and reusing scripts than creating ones of my own, hope that soon I will be able to create custom scripts :)

These days I have searched for a way to clone existing Test Steps from a Test Case into another Test Case. I have searched in the net for some ways or ready scripts that I can implement in my projects, but so far I have no luck finding what I need :(

Can you help me with this by showing me some examples how this can be done?

Kind regards,
Kristiyan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clone a test step (or a whole test case) from one place to another easily enough:

```
def originalTestStep = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
        .getTestSuiteByName("OriginalTestSuite").getTestCaseByName("OriginalTestCase")
        .getTestStepByName("OriginalTestStep")

testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
        .getTestSuiteByName("TargetTestSuite").getTestCaseByName("TargetTestCase")
        .cloneStep(originalTestStep, "clonedTestStep")
```

But, this would be creating a maintenance problem. A better option would be to put your common test steps into a test case and then run *that* test case from your many other test cases. There's a `Run Test Case` test step you can use or you can do it from Groovy:

```
def testCase = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
        .getTestSuiteByName("CommonTestSuite")
        .getTestCaseByName("CommonTestCase")
def properties = new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap ()
testCase.run(properties, false)
```

This way your maintenance is confined to just a few places.

Comment: Thank you! This should work perfectly for the things that I want to do in my projects. When I try to execute it now I am getting a strange result ... I want to record the request and response xmls as files on my drive, but when I use the script it points tries to find them in the Test Case where I have set up the common script and saves them as blanks :

`def myXmlRequest = "Path"
def request = context.expand('${TestCase#Request}') 
def req = new File(myXmlRequest) 
req.write(request, "UTF-8")` 

How can I set the request to take them from the the present test case and not the common?

Comment: You can drill down to a specific suite/case/step/request or response outside your current test case by using something like `testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("OriginalTestSuite").getTestCaseByName("OriginalTestCase").getTestStepByName("OriginalTestStep").getPropertyValue("request")`. Raise a separate question if it gets more involved than this so there's more room to show the code.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI allows you to clone or move a test step from one test to another test.

In the folder structure on the left of the GUI, right-click the step of interest and a context menu will pop-up.  Or, highlight the step and click F9.

A window should appear that asks whether you want to move or copy the step and the destination.

Answer (score 0):

1.Right click on the testcase you want to clone, select "Clone test"
2.Rename the test case. Also, you can select different test case to which you want to clone from the drop down.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UR6p.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).